# Birthday problem Confused with result

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, birthday

So I'm watching a Khan Academy video where it shows you how to solve the birthday problem. He point out that an easy way to do it is to solve first how many people DO NOT have the same birthday. Once you get that you subtract from the 100% of people and get the prob of how many people do.

So the problem I was given was the prob that at least 3 people share the same birthday in a group of $100$.

Following the video I get $\frac{(365!)}{(365-100)! \cdot 365^{100}} = 3.07$ but this does not make any sense since $3.07$ is larger than 1 and if I subtract $3.07$ from 1 i get a negative number.

Comment: He doesn't count how many people don't have the same birthday, he counts how many ways for none of the people to have the same birthday. That's a very different sentence.

Comment: And the probability that at most 2 people share the same birthday (the negation of your problem) is harder to compute than the probability that NO two people share a birthday, since the latter is just k! times N-choose-k over k^N.

Comment: Despite those guys already said, I think you lost a term. It should be ((365!)/((365-100)!100!))/(365^100). You lost the 100!

Comment: That is the number of combinations to pick 100 (unique) out of 365. Not the same problem as counting the number of ways people don't have the same birthday.

Comment: Okay so for example P(at least 3 people have same birthday)+ P( have different birthday) = 1. So that would it be easier to do 1-P(have different birthday)= P(at least 3 people have the same birthday) in this case i was solving for P(have different) which is (365*364*363...because cannot be born on same day)/ (365^n because all of them could have been born on 365 days) so that is why i used ((365!)/265!))/365^100= 3.07 so does this mean that the prob of people haveing the same birthday is higher that 100%???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that at least two people among 100 share birthday $$1 - \frac{365 \cdots 265}{{365}^{100}} = 1- \frac{365!}{(365-100)! \cdot 365^{100}}$$ the second term is $\approx 3\cdot 10^{-7}$ so we are almost sure that some two people share the same birthday. This is not very surprising as already at $\approx 23$ people the chance is greater than $50\%$ ( famous problem I had in school ).

If any two people share a birthday, to avoid that a third shares the same birthday as any of the previous people would be $$365 \cdot 365 \cdot 364 \cdot 364 \cdots 315 / 365^{100} = \frac{\left(\frac{365!}{315!}\right)^2}{365^{100}} \approx 0.09\%$$

The complement to this is $1 - 0.0009 \approx 99.9\%$, so if my way of calculating works it would be almost $99.9\%$ chance that at least some 3 people among 100 should have the same b-day.

Comment: so in other words i would have 1-3.07 = -2.07 meaning that there is over 100 percent that at least 3 people among 100 share the same birthday?

Comment: No, if I'm thinking straight it would mean about $1-0.0009 \approx 99.9\%$ chance that at least some 3 people share the same b-day.

Comment: Clarified the second term for you. Maybe I accidentally tried to edit your answer with that term too. I'm maybe too tired to be doing this. Will proof read in the morning. Sorry for any confusion I may have caused.

Comment: Thank You very much for some reason i thought of 3 instead of 3.07X10^(-7).